# Show that $X$ is homeomorphic to exactly one of the spaces in the following list: $S^2, P^2, K, T_n, T_n\#P^2,T_n\#K, n > 0$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Where X is a space obtained by pasting the edges of a polygonal region together in pairs.

Alternatively: Show that X is homeomorphic to exactly one of the spaces in the following list: $S^2,T_n, P^2, K_m, P^2\#K_m$, where $K_m$ is the m-fold connected sum of $K$(Klein bottle) with itself and $M \geq 0$.

We have the classification theorem: If X is the space obtained from a polygonal region in the plane by pasting its edges together in pairs. Then X is homeomorphic to either $S^2, T_n$ or $P_m$. Where $P_m$ is the m-fold projective plane.

It seems I have to show that one of the things on the list that is not $S^2$ or $T_n$ is homeomorphic to $P_m$? The likely candidates seem to be, for the list in the title: $T_n\#P^2$. For the second list: $P^2\#K_m$. But I'm not sure if these are correct and how to formally show that those are homeomorphic to $P_m$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the applications of the Euler characteristic in the context of algebraic topology.  $X$ is any polygonal region, not one in particular.

Comment: Let me try to write something.

Comment: Cool, thanks :)

Comment: Okay. Hopefully that helps. Please comment if my notation is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than solving the problem for you, I collect here all relevant facts. Given these facts, actually solving it should be fairly straightforward.

**Convention.** Write $T_0$ for the $2$-sphere.

**Classification Theorem.** Suppose $X$ is a compact surface.

- If $X$ is orientable, then $X \cong T_n$ for some integer $n \geq 0$.
- If $X$ is non-orientable, then $X \cong P_n$ for some integer $n \geq 1$.

> **Definition.** Letting $\chi$ denote the Euler characteristic function, define $\psi$ as the function on compact surfaces given as
>   follows. $$\psi(X) = 2 - \chi(X).$$

**Proposition 0.**

- $\psi(X \,\#\,Y) = \psi(X)+\psi(Y),$ for all compact surfaces $X$ and $Y$.
- $\psi(T_0) = 0$

**Proposition 1.** $\psi(T) = 2, \psi(P) = 1$

**Corollary.** $\psi(T_n) = 2n, \psi(P_n) = n$

**Proposition 2.** (Dyck's theorem.) $T \,\#\, P = P \,\#\,P\,\#\,P$

**Proposition 3.** If $K$ is the Klein bottle, then:

$$K \cong P \,\#\, P$$

Comment: Well, I understand where you are going. But my classification theorem is formulated much differently and I don't think I'm supposed to use the euler characteristic function. It is proved by showing that if $w$ is the labbeling scheme by which one forms the space $X$ it is equivalent to one of the following schemes: $(1) aa^{-1}bb^{-1}. (2) abab. (3)(a_1a_1)....(a_m(a_m), m>1. (4)(a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}).....(a_nb_na_n^{-1}b_n^{-1}).$ Which gives you either $S^2, P^2, P_m, T_n$.

Comment: @zkxc, fair enough; that is a more "nuts-and-bolts" approach. I can't remember enough about the material to be able to help you, unfortunately. But what I've written is true, and its by far the easiest way to see why every compact surface is necessarily of the relevant form. By the way, you have a typo in your title.

Comment: Good answer anyway, thanks.

Comment: @zkxc, no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to know is that the sum of three projective planes is homeomorphic to the sum of a torus and a projective plane.

Comment: I've actually proved this. How would this help me? The idea I have now is just showing that the labelling scheme $T_n \# P^2$ is equivalent to the labelling scheme of $P_{2n+1}$. But maybe there is an easier way if having proved that $T\#P^2$ is homeomorphic to $P_3$?

Comment: $P_1$ is $P$. $P_2$ is $K$ (that is, a Klein bottle is the sum of two projective planes). $P_3$ is $T\#P$. It follows that $P_{2n}=T_{n-1}\#K$ for $n\ge2$, and $P_{2n+1}=Tn\#P$ for $n\ge1$.

Comment: OK now? Any further questions?